# Access `$scope` in Repeating AngularJS Directive with Function as Template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I access an object from an `ng-repeat` that is passed into a directive, when the directive is using a function for its template?

I have the following `ng-repeat` set up in a directive:

```
<my-directive ng-repeat="item in list.contents" item="item"></my-directive>

app.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      item: '='
    },
    template: function (element, attrs) {
      // pseudo-code
      if (item.type == "typeA")
        return '<li>{{ item }} one type</li>';
      else
        return '<li>{{ item }} another type</li>';
    }
  };
});
```

When in the template a `{{ item }}` works fine, but I can't figure out how to reference `item` as the object it was passed in as by the `ng-repeat`. Using the `attrs` I can get the value from the tag, but that value is just a string.

Can I get `type` as an object, as it was passed to the `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to modify your approach. Scope is not accessible from your template function. Instead of using an `if` statement inside your template function, you could use `ng-if` within the template itself.

For example:

**Directive**

```
  app.directive('myDirective',function() { 
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { item: '='},
        template: '<div ng-if="item.type==\'one\'">' + 
                      '{{item.name}}' + 
                  '</div>' + 
                  '<div ng-if="item.type==\'two\'">' +
                      '{{item.name}}' + 
                  '</div>'
     }
  });
```

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller='ctrl'> 
       <my-directive ng-repeat="item in items" item="item"></my-directive>
  </body>
```

**Controller**

```
  app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
       $scope.items = [];
       $scope.items.push({type:'one', name: 'One'});
       $scope.items.push({type:'two', name: 'Two'});
  });
```

[Demo Plunker Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/R7S8wC8UXw2YHlWMS3Rd?p=preview)

Comment: Much thanks! I forgot `ng-if` was added to core Angular a while back.